# joomla scribfire and windows live integration

Tags: joomla, xml-rpc, windows-live-writer

i am trying to use live writer of scribfire in my joomla 1.7.3

neither solution detects automatically. 
i have installed the joomler.net solution.
enabled all plugins.

api adress i put in is:
    Enabled SEF
    http://yoursite.com/component/xmlrpc/
    Disabled SEF
    http://yousite.com/index.php?option=com_xmlrpc

and i installed the library recommended:

still nothing works....

does anybody knows how to solve this?
i have RS firewall installed but even when disabled nothing works...

i will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: for live writer there is a hack- open the component option box, press save while live writer is communicating....sound idiotic, but it works,the automatic identification suddenly works... for scribfire i have no solution yet :)

Comment: ok, scribfire solution is this one,put in this adress in the API adress:yourdomain.xxx/component/xmlrpc/  , it worked, i thought i did it before, any way this time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**live writer solution:**
make sure ACL is configured to Allow for the user (second field only) and not inherited.
also while live writer is communicating with the joomla press save on the component options.
it works!.

**scribfire** was configured secondly so mabye the first solution helped. 
the right API location is:

```
    yourdomain.xxx/component/xmlrpc/
```

have fun.